# Как можно поменять прозрачность background-image не меняя прозрачности остального содержимого блока?

Tags: html, css

Как можно поменять прозрачность картинки через `opacity` заданной с помощью `background-image` не меняя при этом прозрачности всего остального содержимого `div`?

К примеру:

```
<div class="block" style="background-image: pic.jpg;">
    <h1>Текст</h1>
</div>
```

Меняя `opacity` класса "block" естественно будет меняться `opacity` и заголовка в том числе, но нужно только `background-image`

Comment: покажите ваш код ...дальше будет видно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого свойства как background-opacity нет, но есть такая альтернатива: можно заменить background псевдоэлементом, и применить opacity уже к нему.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(http://calculate-this.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/cat-3-icon.png?itok=w4QTmWF4);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Псевдоэлемент

```css
.block {
  width:300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
    background:url(http://on-desktop.com/wps/Nature___Fields_Hilly_landscape_042589_.jpg);
}
.block2 {
  position: relative;
  left:40px;
  top:-140px;
    width:300px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index:1;
}
.block2::before {
  content:"";
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:url(http://on-desktop.com/wps/Nature___Fields_Hilly_landscape_042589_.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  foo bar
</div>
<div class="block2">
  baku reku
</div>
```

Comment: можно же `inherit` не обязательно  указывать url

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, `inherit` не будет работать в таком случае. Так как оно наследует свойство от родительского элемента. У `block2` нет  `background`, соответственно нечего наследовать.

Comment: @Arthur  смотри мой пример ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ты не понял. `block1` & `block2` существуют отдельно. В примере Duoxx'a псевдоэлемент  у `block2`, в котором не может работать наследование.

Comment: @Arthur  ну можно обернуть в один контейнер и тогда будет наследование работать

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я про это и говорю=)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77796/discussion-between---and-arthur).

Answer (score 0):

Если это просто какой-то цвет, то можно задать его с помощью `rgba`.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  text
</div>
```

А если картинка, то никак. Можно воспользоваться `png` фоном, либо сделать замену, когда нужно, например если экран стал маленький и нужно сделать фон прозрачным, то можно использовать `media` и просто подменить на картинку с нужной прозрачностью.

Хотя думаю, что найдутся какие-нибудь костыльные варианты

Comment: Ну как костыль вариант Duoxx с абсолютным позиционированием который пришел мне в голову. Если картинка то я думаю перенести содержимое блока в соседний блок лучшее решение.

Comment: @Telion, да, я тоже об этом подумал.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, если фон из фото и надо его сделать прозрачным можно поступить этим способом

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://nevseoboi.com.ua/uploads/posts/2012-02/1328215556-496551-0031795_www.nevseoboi.com.ua.jpg);
  background-size: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.item:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .4;
}

.item p {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore veniam similique libero adipisci officia unde, est neque harum. Corrupti ut consequatur totam maiores eveniet amet doloremque voluptatibus nostrum eaque nam dignissimos recusandae fuga ab,
    deleniti quo eligendi, repellat ea fugiat nesciunt reiciendis. Hic deleniti praesentium maxime esse consequuntur ut nesciunt!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос мог устареть, но вот еще решение - может кому пригодится.
Прозрачность картинки задать с помощью градиента.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('path to image');
```

rgba можно подобрать самостоятельно с помощью любого конвертера цветов